# select distinct Id with different names asociated and select also the names related to the id selected :/

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

My title sounded like a tongue twister, so let me explain myself better. I have a table with very bad data quality in which I have the following case:

```
CustomerId CustomerName
1          Jhon
1          Mary
2          Tom
```

CustomerId is not the key of the table.

I need to populate a Dictionary with the list but when I did the following:

```
select distinct CustomerId, CustomerName from FullTransactions
```

it returned the previous data set, and then when I tried to populate the combobox launched an exception because I am not allowed to repeat the same key.

Do you suggest any workaround to make a select distinct in which return a unique customerId, I don't mind if is selecting just one of the customernames or merging in a name every occurrence...

```
CustomerId CustomerName
1          Jhon-Mary
2          Tom
```

Hope I explained myself better now...
Thank you very much in advance for any light you can bring...

Comment: which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17285.0, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2017, you can use aggregate function `string_agg()`:

```
select 
    CustomerId , 
    string_agg(CustomerName, '-') within group (order by CustomerName) CustomerName
from mytable
group by CustomerId
```

In earlier versions, a solution is to use `for xml path` and `stuff()`:

```
select distinct 
    t.CustomerId,
    stuff(
        (
            select distinct ',' + t1.CustomerName
            from mytable t1
            where t1.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        1,
        0,
        ''
    ) CustomerName
from mytable t;
```